# Django webpack loader vuejs+typescript Refused to execute script frombecause its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable

Tags: django, typescript, webpack, django-webpack-loader

I am using `Django` as backend and `Vue3` as frontend in my application. In development server i did not have problem but now in production i am having problems to render the page. I have followed all the documentations but cannot find a solution.

I am using `django-webpack-loader` to render the bundle which I formed using `webpack5`. But now i am getting an error hence thinking that `django` is trying to render `fallback` page.

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://medtourism.uk/app-a7abdc6b502c1335fd69.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

My `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
   mode:'production',
   entry:{
    app: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main.ts'),
   },
   output: {
     filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/dist'),
     clean: true,
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.vue$/,
          use: 'vue-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options: {
            appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: [ "style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/i,
          // More information here https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/
          type: "asset",
        },
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
      alias: {
        'vue': '@vue/runtime-dom',
        'bulma': 'bulma/css/bulma.css',
      }
    },
   plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
     new BundleTracker({
        filename: './webpack-stats.json',
        publicPath: '/'
      })
   ]
 };
```

my typescript config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noLib": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/*.vue"
  ]
}
```

In Django:

```
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'CACHE': not DEBUG,
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'dist/',  # must end with slash
        'STATS_FILE': '/home/ytsejam/public_html/medtourism/medtourism/frontend/webpack-stats.json',
        'POLL_INTERVAL': 0.1,
        'TIMEOUT': None,
        'IGNORE': [r'.+\.hot-update.js', r'.+\.map'],
        'LOADER_CLASS': 'webpack_loader.loader.WebpackLoader',
    }
}
```

and my index.html:

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>Medtourism</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but frontend doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
<div id="app"></div>
{% render_bundle 'app' %}
<!-- built files will be auto injected -->
</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual reason for this error message is that when the browser tries to load that resource, the server returns an HTML page instead, for example if your router catches unknown paths and displays a default page without a 404 error. Of course that means the path does not return the expected CSS file / image / icon / whatever.

To make sure you are in that case, copy the path and try to access it directly in a new browser window or tab. You will see what your server sends.

That said, check your configuration and maybe examples of integration on github like this one https://github.com/tmpbook/django-with-vuejs